# useEffect being triggered multiple times and I do not know what to change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Last edit of the night. Tried to clean some things up to make it easier to read. also to clarify what is going on around the useEffect. Because I am running react in strict mode everything gets rendered twice. The reference around the useEffect makes sure it only gets rendered 1 time.

Db is a firebase reference object. I am grabbing a list of league of legends games from my database.
one I have all my games in the snapshot variable, I loop through them to process each game.
each game contains a list of 10 players. using a puuId I can find a specific player. We then pull the data we care about in addChamp.
The data is then put into a local map. We continue to update our local map untill we are done looping through our database data.
After this I attempt to change our state variable in the fetchMatches function.
My issue now is that I am stuck in an infinite loop. I think this is because I am triggering another render after the state gets changed.

```
import { useState, useEffect, /*useCallback,*/ useRef } from 'react'
import Db from '../Firebase'

const TotGenStats = ({ player }) => {
  const [champs, setChamps] = useState(new Map())
  var init = new Map()
  var total = 0
  console.log("entered stats")

  const addChamp = /*useCallback(*/ (item) => {
    console.log("enter add champ")
    var min = item.timePlayed/60
    //var sec = item.timePlayed%60
    var kda = (item.kills + item.assists)/item.deaths
    var dub = 0
    if(item.win){
      dub = 1
    }

    var temp = {
      name: item.championName,
      avgCs: item.totalMinionsKilled,
      csMin: item.totalMinionsKilled/min,
      kds: kda,
      kills: item.kills,
      deaths: item.deaths,
      assists: item.assists,
      wins: dub,
      totalG: 1
    }

    init.set(item.championName, temp)
    //setChamps(new Map(champs.set(item.championName, temp)))
  }//,[champs])

  const pack = /*useCallback( /*async*/ (data) => {
    console.log("enter pack")
    for(const item of data.participants){
      //console.log(champ.assists)
      if(item.puuid === player.puuid){
        console.log(item.summonerName)

        if(init.has(item.championName)){//only checking init??
          console.log("update champ")
        }
        else{
          console.log("add champ")
          /*await*/ addChamp(item)
        }
      }
    }
  }/*,[addChamp, champs, player.puuid])*/

  const fetchMatches = async () => {
    console.log("enter fetch matches")
    Db.collection("summoner").doc(player.name).collection("matches").where("queueId", "==", 420)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        //console.log("loop")
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        console.log("total: ", ++total);
        await pack(doc.data());
      });
    })
    .then( () => {
      setChamps(init)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error getting doc", error);
    });
  }



  const render1 = useRef(true)
  useEffect( () => {
    console.log("enter use effect")
    if(render1.current){
      render1.current = false
    }
    else{
      fetchMatches();
    }
  })

  return(
    <div>
      <ul>
        {[...champs.keys()].map( k => (
          <li key={k}>{champs.get(k).name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TotGenStats
```

Newest Version. no longer infinitly loops, but values do not display/render.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Db from '../Firebase'

const TotGenStats = ({ player }) => {
  const [champs, setChamps] = useState(new Map())
  var total = 0
  console.log("entered stats")

  const addChamp = /*useCallback(*/ (item) => {
    console.log("enter add champ")
    var min = item.timePlayed/60
    //var sec = item.timePlayed%60
    var kda = (item.kills + item.assists)/item.deaths
    var dub = 0
    if(item.win){
      dub = 1
    }

    var temp = {
      name: item.championName,
      avgCs: item.totalMinionsKilled,
      csMin: item.totalMinionsKilled/min,
      kds: kda,
      kills: item.kills,
      deaths: item.deaths,
      assists: item.assists,
      wins: dub,
      totalG: 1
    }

    return temp
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    var tempChamp = new Map()

    Db.collection("summoner").doc(player.name).collection("matches").where("queueId","==",420)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id," => ", doc.data());
        console.log("total: ", ++total);
        for(const person of doc.data().participants){
          if(player.puuid === person.puuid){
            console.log(person.summonerName);
            if(tempChamp.has(person.championName)){
              console.log("update ", person.championName);
              //add update
            }else{
              console.log("add ", person.championName);
              var data = await addChamp(person);
              tempChamp.set(person.championName, data);
            }

          }
        }
      })//for each
      setChamps(tempChamp)
    })
  },[player.name, total, player.puuid]);

  return(
    <div>
      <ul>
        {[...champs.keys()].map( k => (
          <li key={k}>{champs.get(k).name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TotGenStats
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense to me, thank you Sean. Is there a recommended way to go about this? should i make a non state map, then one the snapshot data has been processed, just make the state map == the non state map

Comment: I think I am a little bit confused, where should I call the set state function once I am done mapping the data? if I put it in the useEffect hook after my call to fetch matches I think i end up with the same error

Comment: Kinda sounds like the parent might be rerendering, and then recreating the child component; therefore, causing the useEffect to be run on the first render of the child component

Answer (score 0):

useEffect will be called only once when you will not pass any argument to it and useEffect works as constructor hence its not possible to be called multiple times

```
useEffect( () => {
  },[])
```

If you pass anything as argument it will be called whenever that argument change is triggered and only in that case useEffect will be called multiple times.

```
 useEffect( () => {
  },[arg])
```

Though whenever you update any state value in that case component will re-render. In order to handle that situation you can use [useCallback or useMemo](https://medium.com/@guptagaruda/react-hooks-understanding-component-re-renders-9708ddee9928#204b).

Also for map operation directly doing it on state variable is not good idea instead something like following[[source]](https://azimi.io/es6-map-with-react-usestate-9175cd7b409b):

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(new Map())
const add = (key, value) => {
  setState(prev => new Map([...prev, [key, value]]))
}
```

I have made some edits to your latest code try following:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Db from "../Firebase";

const TotGenStats = ({ player }) => {
  const [champs, setChamps] = useState(new Map());

  const addChamp = (item) => {
    let min = item.timePlayed / 60;
    let kda = (item.kills + item.assists) / item.deaths;
    let dub = null;
    if (item.win) {
      dub = 1;
    } else {
      dub = 0;
    }
    let temp = {
      name: item.championName,
      avgCs: item.totalMinionsKilled,
      csMin: item.totalMinionsKilled / min,
      kds: kda,
      kills: item.kills,
      deaths: item.deaths,
      assists: item.assists,
      wins: dub,
      totalG: 1,
    };
    setChamps((prev) => new Map([...prev, [item.championName, temp]]));
  };

  const pack = (data) => {
    for (const item of data.participants) {
      if (item.puuid === player.puuid) {
        if (!champs.has(item.championName)) {
          addChamp(item);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const fetchMatches = async () => {
    Db.collection("summoner")
      .doc(player.name)
      .collection("matches")
      .where("queueId", "==", 420)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
          await pack(doc.data());
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  };

  const render1 = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMatches();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {[...champs.keys()].map((k) => (
          <li key={k}>{champs.get(k).name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TotGenStats;
```

Comment: Hi Harshit, I made a mistake including that in the code i posted here. I have been experimenting different ways to run this. If i do not include the dependancy array the output repeats 8 times.

Comment: Dan - In that case it seems to be issue with method handling because in useEffect you are only calling *fetchMatches* which will be for sure called once while component loads you can crosscheck that. In fetchMatches you are calling pack method multiple times which is updating state. Can you explain bit more on issue with some sample data?

Comment: Also you are directly trying to preform action on state variable which is not recommended. I have added edit to my answer hope that helps.

Comment: Harshit - I made a local variable to hold all the values of the map now, and I am updating state at the very end once everything has been mapped. Now I am infinity looping because i am changing state. at least I think this is my problem, I can get some sample output in a second.